# kali linux Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, kali-linux

im trying to install software center in kali linux but every time it was giving me error Package  has no installation candidate

Comment: Are you trying to install `synaptic` or `software-center`?  Your question doesn't make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

and try again. If that doesn't work, then post the contents of `/etc/sources.list`